# Extracting first and last name from contacts with sed

Tags: sed, extract

So i have a few first and last names in this format

```
firstname=John
lastname=Smith
adress=...

firstname=Whatever
lastname=Random
adress=...
```

How would i extract it in **firstname-lastname** format?

```
John-Smith
```

Comment: It would be 372.83 times easier with `awk` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^firstname=/{s///;h};/^lastname=/{s///;H;x;s/\n/-/;p}' file
```

Output:

```
John-Smith
Whatever-Random
```

---

The first part (`/^firstname=/{s///;h}`) copies the part right from `firstname=` to `sed`'s hold space.

The longer second part (`/^lastname=/{s///;H;x;s/\n/-/;p}`) appends the part right from `lastname=` to `sed`'s hold space. Hold space contains now "John" with a trailing newline and "Smith" (e.g.). Then it swaps (`x`) content of `sed's` hold space and its pattern space and replaces (with `s/\n/-/`) in pattern space the embedded newline (`\n`) by `-` and then prints (`p`) `sed`'s pattern space.

Comment: `s///` seems to match the regex in the address. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I don't know. Some GNU sed features are not documented in its manpage oder infopage.

Comment: Oh, it's actually [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses), under `/regexp/` - "the empty regular expression `//` repeats the last regular expression match..."